# Trying to get information from postgresql database, based on a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

1. This is my first time working with node and postgre. I am trying to get the email, first name, and last name from my postgre database by passing in a user's email address in a SQL statement:

   ```
    function getSingleUser(req, response, next){
    var UserId = req.params.email.substring(1);
    console.log(UserId);
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
   if(err){
       return console.error('Error fetching client from pool', err);
   }

   client.query('SELECT users.email, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.id FROM people.users WHERE users.lastname = Williams', function(err, results){

       if(err){
           return console.log('error running query', err);
       }


       // Just returns the raw json data
       response.json(results.rows); 
       client.release();


       done();
   });
   });
   };
   ```

Whenever I run this though I get the error: error running query { error: column "williams" does not exist. So what can I use to check for a value and not a column? Thank you

Comment: I know that this takes in no parameter I just wanted to hardcode it and try to get back all of Williams information before I pass in a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it by adding single quotes around my parameter and double quotes around everything else.

```
 client.query("SELECT users.email, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.id FROM people.users WHERE users.lastname = '" + UserId + "'"
```